# Page doesn't scroll to form if validation errors are shown

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, forms, validation

I have a FreeForm form at the bottom of a page. When the form is submitted and returns with a validation message, the user is bounced back up to the top of the page. Is there a way to make sure the page is scrolled down at the same place in the document so the user isn't disoriented?

Answer (score 0):

The nature of freeform is to actually visit another URL on submit and on error return to the previous (form page).

I'd look at implementing a JavaScript check prior and/or use Ajax to submit.

Failing that I do recall an option to setup freeform with inline error checking.

Double check the freeform docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inline_error_return parameter to set the return path to the current page then add in a link to an anchor.

Docs:
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#inline_error_return

Example I have used in the past:

Inline_error_return="template_name#anchor"

You could change the #anchor to the css form ID and it will load the page in the correct position.